# prism5 regionManager.RequestNavigate is showing System.object

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, prism-4

I am using prism5 with regionManager. Following is how I registered my views and how I am trying to navigate.

```
_container.RegisterType<IMyView,MyView>("MyView");
```

and this is how I am navigating

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate("MyViewRegion", new Uri("MyView", UriKind.Relative);
```

This one navigates to MyViewRegion but only shows System.Object

Some say to fix this by registering the views as follows

```
_container.RegisterType<object,MyView>("MyView");
```

But I still want to register my view with an interface type. So how could I fix this with `RequestNavigate();`

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "shows System.Object"?  Shows it where?

Comment: It shows on the main region where screen is supposed to be loaded. Instead it shows System.Object

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this problem which was caused when attempting to navigate to a view that was not loaded. I therefore use a simple function that I call before I call the .RequestNavigate method to check the view has been loaded:

```
    private void LoadViewInRegion<TViewType>(IRegion region, string viewName)
    {
        object view = region.GetView(viewName);
        if (view == null)
        {
            view = _container.Resolve<TViewType>();

            region.Add(view, viewName);
        }
    }
```

So the code to display the view would be something like:

```
IRegion region = _regionManager.Regions["MyViewRegion"];

LoadViewInRegion<IMyView>(region, "MyView");

_regionManager.RequestNavigate("MyViewRegion", new Uri("MyView", UriKind.Relative);
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit and I am loading the code inside my module class Initialize method. Most of the other suggestions online were no help for Prism 5.

```
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainNavigationRegion",
            typeof(Views.TestDocumentNavigationView));

        LoadViewInRegion<TestDocumentView>("MainRegion");
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// You must load the views in order for the navigation to resolve
    /// </summary>
    void LoadViewInRegion<TViewType>(string regionName)
    {
        IRegion region = _regionManager.Regions[regionName];
        string viewName = typeof(TViewType).Name;

        object view = region.GetView(viewName);
        if (view == null)
        {
            view = _container.Resolve<TViewType>();

            region.Add(view, viewName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to register your views in Module.cs/App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
     containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ViewA>();
     containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ViewB>();
}
```

**And your problem will be resolved :)**